# Emacs: hook for when opening XML file

Tags: emacs, elisp

I put these in my configuration file:

```
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook (lambda () (message "SGML")))
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook (lambda () (message "HTML")))
(add-hook 'xml-mode-hook  (lambda () (message "XML")))
```

When opening .html file, it prints "SGML" and "HTML" as expected.
But when opening .xml file, none is printed.

Question: so how do I add hook for xml files?

Comment: On my emacs (GNU emacs 23.2.1 on OS X), the default major mode for XML is called `nXML`, with the associated `nxml-mode-hook`.  Perhaps `xml-mode` is not your XML major mode either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried nxml-mode instead, as in:

```
(add-hook 'nxml-mode-hook  (lambda () (message "XML")))
```

Answer (score 2):

*Note:* This answer applies to Emacs 22 and earlier.  For Emacs 23+, see the accepted answer.

XML mode is an alias for SGML mode.  You can test to see if you're in the XML or SGML variant by checking the variable `sgml-xml-mode` like so:

```
(add-hook 'sgml-mode-hook (lambda () (message (if sgml-xml-mode "XML" "SGML"))))
```

The mode is documented in the manual [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/HTML-Mode.html).

Comment: on my emacs sgml-mode-hook is not called when opening .xml file

Comment: Ah, yes, I was playing around with an older Emacs, the latest uses nxml.